# scala - get random Special Character (symbol)

Tags: scala

I would like to generate a password in scala with all types of characters

So I have this method:

*randomAlpha(1).toLowerCase + randomAlpha(1).capitalize + Random.nextInt(10) + Random.alphanumeric.take(passwordLength - 3).mkString*

that will provide me a password with 8 random characters when it contains LowerCase and UpperCase

But I would like to add a single random Special character

"~`!@#$^%&*()_-+={}[]|;:"'<,>.?/"

any idea?

thanks!

Comment: You can make an array consisting of these characters, and you can behave a random integer in `[0, arrayLength)` as the index to the array.

Comment: `Random.shuffle("~!@#$^%&*()_-+={}[]|;:"'<,>.?/").head`

Comment: I assume, you do realize that this is a VERY BAD way to generate passwords, and are not going to use it in any production system, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks Dima. this is working for me. I goal is to generate passwords for dummy users (testing only) not for production

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ideas, but I shall show you 2 of them.

You could for example make your own list of special character and random choose one of them if you want certain characters. For simplicity, you can use a raw string to avoid being confused by escaping certain special characters.

You could also choose to use `Random.nextPrintableChar` which as per documentation:

> *returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed value from the ASCII range 33-126.*

This can be any printable character excluding space, but including an alphanumeric char. Alternatively you could call this multiple times until you get a nonalphanumeric char.

Here's how you could do that:

```
object Something extends App {

  import scala.language.postfixOps

  val specialChar = Random.shuffle("""~!@#$^%&*()_-+={}[]|;:"'<,>.?/""").head

  val nonAlphaNumericChar = {
    var c = Random.nextPrintableChar
    while (c.isLetterOrDigit)
      c = Random.nextPrintableChar
    c
  }

  val mySpecialPassword = (Random.alphanumeric take 7 mkString) + specialChar

  val myRandomPassword =
    (Random.alphanumeric take 7 mkString) + nonAlphaNumericChar

  println(s"My dummy password is: $mySpecialPassword")
  println(s"My dummy password is: $myRandomPassword")
}
```

Outputs:

```
My dummy password is: OyAsy5h^
My dummy password is: rZDxS2N=
```